# How to check if data already exists on table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-design

so, I have some problem checking if table got some data

So, I coded the following in Mysql

```
DECLARE ifnumber INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT CASE WHEN id IS NULL 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result INTO ifnumber FROM { table } WHERE { column } = { data };
IF ( ifnumber = 1 ) THEN
    blah blah blah
END IF;
```

It works when the table contains data, but it doesn't when the table is null.

some help?

Ps: I was trying to do an IF with the Exists() function but didn't work for me.

Comment: Tables can't "be null", columns can.  Where did `id` come from?

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` isn't a function...

But if you just want to check if there's any record matching a `WHERE` clause in a table, you might indeed use `EXISTS`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM elbat
                  WHERE ...) THEN
  ...
END IF;
```